# How to retain the last video frame of a video using CCVideoPlayer class?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, ccvideoplayer

I'm using CCVideoPlayer class in one of my iPhone/iPad apps to play the video on various types of gestures.
As of now, when the video ends, I replace the video with a jpeg image of the last frame of the video.

Is there anyway using which I can retain the video's last frame so that I don't have to replace with a jpeg everytime?